# Lifting one vertex of a regular pentagon

Tags: geometry

I feel like this should be (relatively) easy and straightforward, but I keep running into very complicated solutions, which cannot be the answer. This is a visual for what my situation looks like.

[image]

Take a regular pentagon with vertices ABCDE and sides with lenght $d$. Draw a circle with the center at the middle point between C and E trough D, perpendicular to the plane - so the circle is standing up in the z-direction. Now start moving D along this circle. This keeps the distances CD and DE equal, but changes angles BCD and DEA.

I need to know the change of angle BCD (or DEA) as a function of the distance $q$ of vertex D above the plane of the original pentagon.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Use angel created between new D and original D and the pentagon plane to have q as function of d

Comment: Sure, but that is not my question.

Comment: Well... you are expected to make some effort of your own.

Comment: Of course. However, I don't think knowing q as a function of d gets me much closer to a solution, unless I am missing something obvious...

Comment: If you know vectors, you can proceed quite easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By law of cosines on triangles $BCG$ and $GFM$ (where $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$), I get $\cos(\beta) = \frac{1}{4}\left(1 - \sqrt{5} \cos(\alpha)\right)$.

Since $q = \sin(\alpha) \cos(54^\circ)$, that means that $\cos(\alpha) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{q^2}{\cos^2 (54^\circ)}}$, so $$\cos(\beta) =  \frac{1}{4}\left(1 - \sqrt{5} \sqrt{1 - \frac{q^2}{\cos(54^\circ)^2}}\right)$$